# use croogo as plugin in main cakephp app

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, croogo

Im working with cakephp for few months and recently I came across croogo, a cakephp cms system. I've tried it and I should say its an awesome system. 
Is it possible to use it as a plugin in my main site. I want to use it just for the admin part and rest of my application unattached to it. Ive tried loading its bootstrap file from my main app and also by linking routes to it. I always get errors.

Can someone have any idea if croogo is meant to be used like a plugin or does it have to be used seperately?

Comment: "Beginning version 1.6.x, Croogo has been updated to be installed as a vendor package" => So yes, it is possible to use it in your code - just not as plugin, but vendor.

Answer (score 0):

"Beginning version 1.6.x, Croogo has been updated to be installed as a vendor package"

=> So yes, it is possible to use it in your code - just not as plugin, but vendor.

See
https://github.com/croogo/croogo/tree/3.0#installation-using-git

Comment: I'm searching for a while about how to use croogo from vendor. Do you have any idea or any good sources which explains about using vendor files?

Comment: You'll need to adapt your bootstrap files for Croogo similar to how it's done in https://github.com/croogo/app/.

Please note that it's not really intended for use this way though.

Comment: since they've updated to use it as a vendor, shouldn't there be a way to adopt it in my project in a proper way? @rchavik